# rendering content dynamically in react-native with expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have an array called data, of trip details, like this:

[

{
departure: "10:00",
endingLocation: "Australia",
receiptNo: 525352,
startingLocation: "USA",
timeFormat: "AM"
}

]

I want to create a Text component inside a View component, for each entry in the array, using all the fields. For example, "Trip from {startingLocation} to {endingLocation}", as one text in a view. I tried using FlatList provided by expo but it is too complicated. How do I dynamically render the content and return it

I am trying this but it is not working

```
    function renderComponents(){
        
        return (

            data.map(eachPayment => {

                listOfPayments.push(
                    <View>
                        <Text> {eachPayment} </Text>
                    </View>
                )

            })
        )
    }

    return (

        renderComponents()

    )
```

the second return is responsible for rendering the page content

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are returning a list of `<View />` components to your render function, which is not what `React` is expecting.

Ideally, in your render function, you should only return a root component and in there you can return the rest. Please have a look at the following example.

`FlatList` is expecting you to supply an array of data and define a function as to how to display it in the `renderItem` function.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, FlatList, Text } from 'react-native';

const DATA = [
  {
    id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
];


const App = () => {

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Text>{item.title}</Text>
  );

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```